# Cannot change Live Id in Onenote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I am using Windows 8 Pro. I installed Office 2010 includoing OneNote 2010. When I run OneNote and I try to open a notebook from SkyDrive, it shows me another Live Id as logged in. When I click the Not XX button to logout, It does not work, I see a progress ring for a few seconds and then it is back to the previously logged Live Id. How do I get OneNote working with my Live Id and my notebooks on SkyDrive? The Live Id that is logged into my Skydrive in OneNote is a Live Id I used exacty once to acces Windows Store as a developer.

Comment: When you say it "does not work" describe in detail what happens.

Comment: I click Not XXX, see a progress ring for a few seconds and then it goes back to seeing the Live Id as logged user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by deleting all the data (cache, cookies, sessions etc.) from IE10 (which I never use).